# How to share Photo on facebook page through iphone app?

Tags: facebook, ios4, ios5

I want to Share a Photo on facebook page that some one else created but the page is public.

I am using share kit API for iPhone sharing on own wall.

Comment: please help me how can share image on facebook Page